# How to get this DIV to reach to the viewport bottom?

Tags: html

What change to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<div style='background-color:lime;height:100%'>
<p>line 1</p>
<div style='background-color:pink'>
<p>line 2</p>
<p>line 3</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/naqE6/ which shows (current outcome):

[image]

will show (desired outcome):

[image]

with the green DIV stretching as needed to hold its content and the pink DIV stretching as needed to reach the viewport bottom (EDIT: and not further, causing a scroll bar), for any viewport size.

I've seen other answers here inc. to the Holy Grail problem, but none seems address this case. Before you consider marking this as a duplicate, please note: "...*this* DIV...".

Above pics are from Google Chrome.

Comment: You may need to clarify your question.. it's not clear from the fiddle, your snippet, or your screenshots what you WANT it end up looking like. Really, I'd suggest looking into the CSS flexbox. It's the solution to just about any layout problems these days.

Comment: What's unclear about http://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Y70.png ??

Comment: Is that your desired outcome? If so, it's not clear from your question.

Comment: Question clarified.

Comment: " I'd suggest looking into the CSS flexbox." I have done. I didn't find a solution there. "It's the solution to just about any layout problems these days." Perhaps there'll be answer here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to fit your desired outcome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color:lime;position:absolute;width:99%;top:20px;bottom:10px;">
            <p>line 1</p>
            <div style="background-color:pink;height:100%;">
                <p>line 2</p>
                <p>line 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't. It shows a vertical scroll bar.

Comment: `width:99%;` rather than `width:100%;` should fix that!

Comment: Misread your comment. I have now also set the `bottom` attribute to >0, to remove the vertical scroll bar. Answer updated to reflect this change.

Comment: Here it still shows a vertical scroll bar and now also an added gap at top. http://i.imgur.com/24yCKQd.png . There?

Comment: When the browser gets small enough, yes. Another approach is setting `height:100%` on html, body, and both the div tags (and removing everything else but the background-color). You will still get some vertical scroll, but you should not get horizontal scroll. Filling height is one of those weird things in HTML/CSS, alongside e.g. the popular issue of vertical alignment, so i don't really have any more concise suggestions. Google around and you might find something odd that works in your specific case.

Comment: "When the browser gets small enough, yes" The requirement states 'for any viewport size.' Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: You can of course deal with overflow in varying ways, depending on what the intended contents are. Which again is why i didn't take the scroll bar into special consideration.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.sizes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='outer' style='background-color:lime'>
<p>line 1</p>
<div id='inner' style='background-color:pink'>
<p>line 2</p>
<p>line 3</p>
<p id='debug'></p>
</div>
</div>
<script>
console.log('------------------------------------------------------------------');
/*global $*/
"use strict";

$( window ).resize( function()
{ 
var x = 0 +
//    +   $('#inner').margin().top
    +   $('#inner').offset().top
    +   $('#inner').border().top
    +   $('#inner').padding().top
        // inner content, inside height
    +   $('#inner').padding().bottom
    +   $('#inner').border().bottom
    +   $('#inner').margin().bottom
    +  $('#outer').padding().bottom
    +  $('#outer').border().bottom
    +  $('#outer').margin().bottom
    + $('body').padding().bottom
    + $('body').border().bottom
    + $('body').margin().bottom;

  var h =   $(window).height() - x;

  $('#inner')[0].style.height = h+'px';
}
);

$( window ).resize();

</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

giving

[image] .

Here is the code having CSS for manually testing the accommodation of all the relevant style attributes http://pastebin.com/kum349TM .

If anyone can suggest a reduction or elimination of the JS, great.